# Escape HTML in array field in struct

Tags: arrays, go, struct, escaping, go-templates

How do I escape HTML when I have an array field in a struct?

For a single show page, this code works:

show.go:

```
err := ShowTmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "show.html", struct {
        Title    string
        SafeBody template.HTML
}{
    t.Title,
    template.HTML(t.BodyHTML),
})
```

For an index page:

index.go

```
type as struct {
        Articles []*Article
    }
var a as

// some code to give a.Articles its values

err := IndexTmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", a)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

index.html:

```
{{with .Articles}}
  {{range .}}
    <a href="/">{{.Title}}</a>
    {{.BodyHTML | html}} // Doesn't work
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```

How do I escape HTML when I'm ranging over a struct field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways:

### 1. With a custom function

You can use a custom function. The [`Template.Funcs()`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs) method allows you to register any custom functions which can be invoked from templates.

Create a simple function which converts a `string` to [`template.HTML`](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML) like this:

```
func ToHtml(s string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(s)
}
```

You can register it like this:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("index.html").
    Funcs(map[string]interface{}{"ToHtml": ToHtml}).Parse(indexHtml))
```

Where just for demonstration purposes `indexHtml` is a `string` of your template:

```
const indexHtml = `{{with .}}
  {{range .}}
    <a href="/">{{.Title}}</a>
    {{ToHtml .BodyHTML}}
  {{end}}
{{end}}
`
```

And you can refer to it and call it from the template like this:

```
{{ToHtml .BodyHTML}}
```

Calling this template with a parameter:

```
a := []struct {
    Title    string
    BodyHTML string
}{{"I'm the title", "I'm some <b>HTML</b> code!"}}

err := t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.html", a)
```

Here's the complete, working example on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/JvPaGSutS4).

### 2. Modifying `Article`

If you can, it would be easier to just change the type of `Article.BodyHTML` to `template.HTML` and then it would be rendered unescaped without further ado. This would also make the intent clear (that it should/does contain safe HTML which will be rendered unescaped).

### 3. Adding a method to `Article`

You can also add a method to the `Article` type which would return its `BodyHTML` field as a `template.HTML` (pretty much what the custom function does in proposition #1):

```
func (a *Article) SafeBody() template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(a.BodyHTML)
}
```

Having this method you can simply call it from the template:

```
  {{range .}}
    <a href="/">{{.Title}}</a>
    {{.SafeBody}}
  {{end}}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Yp-QEOatF2).

Comment: @user3918985 I added 2 more alternative ways.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. Regarding 2., I want to insert Article into a database, so I've defined it as a string.